# Uncaught TypeError: t.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am using billboard.js to create a bar graph. From last two days, it's showing an error(given below). I couldn't find any reason that why this is happening.

Error is:

```
d3.v4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: t.getAttribute is not a function
    at new W (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at V (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at Z (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at pt.each (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at pt.classed (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at ChartInternal.initWithData (ChartInternal.js:242)
    at ChartInternal.init (ChartInternal.js:61)
    at new Chart (Chart.js:28)
    at Object.generate (core.js:52)
W @ d3.v4.min.js:2
V @ d3.v4.min.js:2
Z @ d3.v4.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:2
each @ d3.v4.min.js:2
classed @ d3.v4.min.js:2
initWithData @ ChartInternal.js:242
init @ ChartInternal.js:61
Chart @ Chart.js:28
generate @ core.js:52
createBarGraph @ reports.js:59
initialize @ reports.js:12
(anonymous) @ reports.js:90
```

And my **javascript function** for graph generation is below (**Note**, I have been using the same code from last 2 weeks and it was working, but now the same code shows error).

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        const instance = this;

        var barGraphContainer = $("#barGraph");
        this.createBarGraph(barGraphContainer);
    },

    /**
     * Generates BarChart using generate function of billboard.js
     * 
     * @param {HTML Tag} graphElement
     */
    createBarGraph: function(graphElement) {
        // bar chart
        var barchart = bb.generate({
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ["Monthly Usage", 120, 230, 212, 180, 140, 170, 120, 230, 212, 180, 140, 170]
                ],
                type: "bar",
            },
            bar: {
                width: {
                    ratio: 0.3,
                    max: 300
                }
            },

            color: {
                pattern: ["#99ff66"]
            },

            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: "category",
                    // label: "Your X-axis",
                    categories: ["Jun'16","Jul'16","Aug'16","Sept'16","Oct'16","Nov'16", "Dec'16","Jan'17","Feb'17","Mar'17","Apr'17","May'17"]
                }
            },

            bindto: barGraphContainer
        });
    }
}

$(function() {
    app.initialize();
});
```

Comment: It seems that this is part of a larger object. You have to provide a [MCVE], because the billboard part has no problem. Also, please don't write things like *"this is urgent"*, or *"I need help fast"* in S.O. questions. If you need urgent help S.O. is **not** the adequate place.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, thanks for the advice about not writing things like "this is urgent" and similar stuff, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Apologies for late reply but I have figured out where was the problem.  Problem was with binding graph data to a variable (that represents graph div on the html page, here it is 'graphElement').  It turned out that one can't set a variable as the value of  "bindto" property. I'll write same explanation in my answer though but I would really like to know the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sandeep, according the API `bindto` can receive 3 types

- as String: CSS selector, which selects the bind element
- as HTMLElement: reference of the bind element
- as d3.selection: reference of the bind element wrapped with the d3

https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Options.html#.bindto

If you can provide the full working code, will be more clear to clarify the issue.

---

**Updated answer:**

Well... according your code and the comment that you already did, the radical issue was caused by the `bind` element reference.

So, the first issue was the variable scope (which you already know).

But there is another issue on this.
You're selecting `#barGraph` element with jQuery.
When you do a selection with jQuery, it will return element wrapped with jQuery instance.

As I commented earlier in this post, `billboard.js` can accept bind element in three different types. It means wrapped jQuery element can't be accepted.

So, for 'bindto' option, the element value should be set as:
`bindto: this.barGraphContainer[0]`, which is referencing the raw DOM element rather than the wrapped jQuery element.

Check out the below working demo.

```js
var app = {
 barGraphContainer: null,
 initialize: function() {
  const instance = this;

  this.barGraphContainer = $("#barGraph");
  this.createBarGraph(this.barGraphContainer);
 },

 /**
  * Generates BarChart using generate function of billboard.js
  *
  * @param {HTML Tag} graphElement
  */
 createBarGraph: function(graphElement) {
  // bar chart
  var barchart = bb.generate({
   data: {
    columns: [
     ["Monthly Usage", 120, 230, 212, 180, 140, 170, 120, 230, 212, 180, 140, 170]
    ],
    type: "bar",
   },
   bar: {
    width: {
     ratio: 0.3,
     max: 300
    }
   },

   color: {
    pattern: ["#99ff66"]
   },

   axis: {
    x: {
     type: "category",
     // label: "Your X-axis",
     categories: ["Jun'16","Jul'16","Aug'16","Sept'16","Oct'16","Nov'16", "Dec'16","Jan'17","Feb'17","Mar'17","Apr'17","May'17"]
    }
   },

   bindto: this.barGraphContainer[0]  // or this.barGraphContainer.get(0)
  });
 }
}

$(function() {
 app.initialize();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="barGraph"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jae, I have edited my question and put my full js code (which had the issue). Hope, that's adequate.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for late reply but I have figured out where was the problem.

Problem was with binding graph data to a variable (that represents graph div on the html page, here it is **graphElement**).  It turned out that one can't set a variable as the value of  "bindto" property.

My issue was resolved though but I would really like to know that why one can't set value of **bindto** property with a variable as it happened in my case.